# How to generate metadata for LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to generate a metadata for the LLVM IR i have generated. I want to generate a metadata of the form :

```
!nvvm.annotations = !{!0}
!0 = metadata !{void ()* @foo, metadata !"kernel", i32 1}
```

Where foo is a function in my LLVM IR. Right now I am only able to generate a metadata of the form:

```
!nvvm.annotations = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"kernel"}
```

I used the following code for the above metadata generation.

```
char metaDataArgument[512];
sprintf(metaDataArgument, "%s", pipelineKernelName);
llvm::NamedMDNode *nvvmMetadataNode =  LLVMModule->getOrInsertNamedMetadata("nvvm.annotations");
llvm::MDNode *MDNOdeNVVM = llvm::MDNode::get(*context, llvm::MDString::get(*context, "kernel"));
nvvmMetadataNode->addOperand(MDNOdeNVVM);
```

Could someone tell me how to modify the above code to generate metadata of the required form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your metadata will be a tuple with 3 elements.

- The first one is a global value, which is wrapped when insert in the metadata hierarchy as "ValueAsMetadata" (we can use the Constant subclass since GlobalValues are constant).
- The second is a MDString, you got this one.
- The last one is wrapped as a `ConstantAsMetadata`.

This should look approximately like the follow:

```
SmallVector<Metadata *, 32> Ops; // Tuple operands
GlobalValue *Foo = Mod.getNamedValue("foo");
if (!Foo) report_fatal_error("Expected foo..");

Ops.push_back(llvm::ValueAsMetadata::getConstant(Foo));
Ops.push_back(llvm::MDString::get(*context, "kernel"));

// get constant i32 1
Type *I32Ty = Type::getInt32Ty(*context);
Contant *One = ConstantInt::get(I32Ty, 1);
Ops.push_back(llvm::ValueAsMetadata::getConstant(One));

auto *Node =  MDTuple::get(Context, Ops);
```