# Store BasicBlock/Instruction into metadata

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing an LLVM pass that analyses program and selects several basic blocks. I would like to store a list of selected blocks (BasicBlock*) into global metadata (and read back in subsequent passes). (There will be multiple BB lists, so I don't want to add metadata to BBs / terminator instructions.)

input:

```
Vector<BasicBlock*>
```

expected output:

```
!42 = !{BB1*, BB2*, ...}
```

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082378/how-to-generate-metadata-for-llvm-ir), but I'm not able to convert a BasicBlock or an Instruction (e.g. a BB terminator) such that it is "correctly" saved in the metadata. One possible workaround is to save two strings – function name and BB name, but I would like to have a more robust solution.

Comment: Are these subsequent passes going to be called from the same instance of opt? Or at a later time?

Comment: For now, all passes are called from the same instance of opt, but I would like to have the passes as much independent as possible. Maybe the idea of storing this information in the metadata is wrong, but I like the metadata because of possibility to have more or less independent passes and also human readability of the output.

Comment: I understand. I'm asking because analysis passes cannot (by definition) add or change any metadata to any code. If debugging information is added, you may run into a situation where you simply _cannot_ add any metadata to your blocks or instructions, as well. If you're going to be serializing this information between multiple opt executions, I think metadata is the way to go; if not, I'd consider storing the information in another fashion.